# Table of contents and python dictionaries

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

I've got data stored in an excel file, it looks like this:

```
Cell A1: Chapter1
Cell A2: Sub-chapter1
Cell A3: Sub-chapter2
Cell A4: Chapter2
Cell A5: Sub-chapter1
```

It goes on like that for several hundred rows.

Basically, I'd like to store all this in a python dictionary, with the chapters being the keys and the sub-chapters being the values. I'm looking at an efficient way to transfer this data from excel to my python IDLE.

I understand that the ending result should look like:

```py
mydic = {"Chapter1" : [Sub-chapter1, Sub-chapter2], "Chapter2"... }
```

Spent some time researching this on the internet, but I've absolutely no idea on how to perform this other than manually.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: In case your problem is importing the data in python, you could use pandas and more specifically the pandas function [read_excel()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html). Those data will be imported as a pandas dataframe. Then you can use a for loop to iterate through the cell values and create the dictionary based on your desired conditions

Comment: are you using the pandas API? if you are let me know and i'll post an answer.

Comment: thanks for your answers, I've tried with pandas data frames, but finally ended up using VBA to format my excel sheet and pasted it directly in python. Not pretty, but it worked